# Android kitkat webview plugin support

Tags: android, flash, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

since setPluginState method is depreciated after api level 8,i think i get an error saying plugin could not be loaded into kitkat device. I used it to support flash content in my application,now kitkat doesnt support flash i know,but ive installed an hacked flash apk which should work i think,but how do i make webview load the plugin ?

is there any alternative to setPluginState that we can use to load the flash plugin in webview?

im told,dolphin browser has made it done,so there could be an way to do this.

any help would be nice..

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in the Chrome based WebView shipped with KitKat I'm afraid.

Comment: ya that ive seen everywhere,but i was hoping if someone found a way to do it anyway :(

Comment: my app requires flash support too. Are there is any alternative to WebView in android 4.4 for playing flash files(e.g .swf files).

Answer (score 0):

This method has been eliminated from Android 4.3,So if you need to maintain compatibility you have to compile the project with Android 4.2 and add backward compatibility library through eclipse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually ive compiled the project with api 17 so that's not the issue as its working fine below api level 19.

problem is i want to make it happen in api level 19 that is kitkat also.any help regarding that would be helpful .

Comment: You can set target sdkversion to 19 and keep your sdk target to 4.2 in eclipse.